How to fuzzy query a directory structure in PostgreSQL?
I was able to put together a rough idea for a PostgreSQL query to query over a node table, which contains id, parent__id, slug, and file_url (optional). It's considered a file if it has file_url, otherwise it's a directory.
-- Enable the pg_trgm extension for fuzzy matching
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;

WITH RECURSIVE path_cte AS (
    -- Base case: Start with root nodes
    SELECT 
        id, 
        slug,
        parent__id,
        slug AS path
    FROM 
        node
    WHERE 
        parent__id IS NULL  -- Start from root nodes

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive case: find children using similarity matching with parent path
    SELECT 
        n.id,
        n.slug,
        n.parent__id,
        CONCAT(pc.path, '/', n.slug) AS path
    FROM 
        node n
    JOIN 
        path_cte pc ON n.parent__id = pc.id
        AND similarity(n.slug, pc.slug) > 0.3  -- Adjust the threshold as needed
)

-- Select the final paths for each node
SELECT 
    id,
    path
FROM 
    path_cte
ORDER BY 
    path;

This is where the AI and I got. However, we duly note:

Keep in mind that the similarity condition might introduce cases where nodes do not match their parent due to the similarity threshold. If no similar match is found at a given level, recursion will stop for that branch.

In VSCode, I can search like this:

Or even:

How can I replicate that in PostgreSQL? Given my hierarchical nodes table:
CREATE TABLE nodes (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,        -- Unique identifier for each node
    slug VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,   -- Name or slug of the node
    parent__id INT REFERENCES nodes(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,  -- Parent node ID, referencing the same table
    file_url VARCHAR(255)         -- Optional URL for file associated with the node
);

Or if that is not a good table structure, then what is a good one to be able to search like this in PostgreSQL?
Ideally a user can pass in a path like a Unix file path, and perhaps it splits it at the / slashes (or not), and then does a fuzzy search on each segment relative to the parent, recursively, without finding things that don't match, against a PostgreSQL schema.
Can it be done? If so, how? If not, where does it become impossible, and what is possible close to this?
Otherwise, this is what I'm doing in JS:
export async function search({ searchTerm }: { searchTerm: string }) {
  return await db
    .selectFrom('image')
    .select('path')
    .where(
      sql<boolean>`similarity(path, ${sql.lit(
        searchTerm,
      )}::text) > ${sql.lit(similarityThreshold)}::float`,
    )
    .orderBy(
      sql`similarity(path, ${sql.lit(searchTerm)}::text)`,
      'desc',
    )
    .execute()
}

Doesn't seem like that will cut it.

Ending up going with something like this perhaps?
WITH RECURSIVE search_nodes AS (
  SELECT
    jsonb_array_elements_text('$1'::jsonb) AS node,
    row_number() OVER () AS search_pos
),
matched_images AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    jsonb_array_elements_text(path) AS path_node,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS path_pos
  FROM image
),
path_matches AS (
  -- Base case: match first search term
  SELECT
    mn.id,
    mn.path_pos as last_pos,
    1 as terms_matched
  FROM search_nodes sn
  JOIN matched_images mn
    ON similarity(sn.node, mn.path_node) > 0.3
  WHERE sn.search_pos = 1

  UNION ALL

  -- Recursive case: match subsequent terms
  SELECT
    mn.id,
    mn.path_pos,
    pm.terms_matched + 1
  FROM path_matches pm
  JOIN search_nodes sn
    ON sn.search_pos = pm.terms_matched + 1
  JOIN matched_images mn
    ON mn.id = pm.id
    AND similarity(sn.node, mn.path_node) > 0.3
    AND mn.path_pos > pm.last_pos
)
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM path_matches
WHERE terms_matched = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM search_nodes);

